# How to interpret a linear mixed model formula

Tags: mixed-model, inference, repeated-measures, random-effects-model, glmm

In this model:

> Biomass ~ Species + (1|Site / Species)

`Biomass` and `Species` are continuous variables,  and `Site` is categorical.

We can see that `Biomass` is the model's response while `Species` is the predictor. What's more, a random effect is added to the model's intercept, because there is a `(1 | R)` term.

But, what does `Site / Species` mean?

Comment: `1|Site/Species` is the random effect on the slope of `Site` and `Species` within `Site`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term `(1|Site/Species)` means that you have 2 levels of clustering. So you have measurements of `Biomass` of individuals, these individuals are clustered within `Species`, and `Species` are clustered/nested within `Site`.  This means that any particular `Species` "belongs" to only one `Site`. If you have the same `Species` within different `Site`s, then you have crossed, not nested, random effects, and probably what you should use (if you have sufficient `Sites` and `Species`) is `(1|Site) + (1|Species)`.

The model will specify random intercepts for both `Site` and `Species`, and so `Species` should not also be a fixed effect.

See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/228800/crossed-vs-nested-random-effects-how-do-they-differ-and-how-are-they-specified/228814#228814) for more information about nested and crossed random effects.